# How can I determine maximum supported display resolution?

Tags: settings, display

I have laptop with:
Dual-Core Intel i5 CPU (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/43544/intel-core-i5540m-processor-3m-cache-2-53-ghz.html)

and I would like to determine maximum supported display resolution (in order to connect external monitor)

am using HDMI to connect laptop(Dell Latitude E6410) to external monitor (benq GW2765 with native resolution 2560x1440)

At the moment only available max resolution in Settings in EOS is 1920x1080 and I want to change it to 2560x1440 (which is a native resolution for my LCD monitor)

but it is not shown as an option?

Want to see whether it is because it is not supported by laptop
or can I change something in Elementary?
I am running 6.1 Jolnir

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

xrandr didn't work :-(

I wasn't able to add the display mode I wanted, but...

I learned how to use dual monitor with Elementary (very easy)

I have changed external monitor settings to scale 1:1 to avoid distortion caused by using non-native display

and now with my CAD application shared between two screens (see below) it is reasonably usable

I am now convinced that the limitation is my laptop rather than anything else

(I have checked what GPU is available on laptop, using `lspci` command)

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

so, it sounds like I am stuck with this one :-(

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
Well... I was WRONG :-)

it is possible to add another display resolution!

The trick is to run `xrandr` before doing anything else to establish which monitor/connection is called what (as you @Vlad have quite correctly pointed out and I have missed ...)

The result:
[image]

You can see that 2560x1440 is available to choose!

Resulting display still has black areas around it,

but it is definitely usable (especially when using both monitors)

This maybe related to the message I get when setting output of HDMI to new mode? (I don't like the word `failed` ??)

```
bambuko@LatitudeE641005543265:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Further confirmed by running:

```
bambuko@LatitudeE641005543265:~$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*HDMI-1 1920/597x1080/336+0+0  HDMI-1
 1: +eDP-1 1280/303x800/190+320+1080  eDP-1
```

where it should be (if successful)

```
+HDMI-1 2560/***x1440/***+*+* HDMI-1
```

searching the web for `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed`

returns a lot, but none of it makes any sense to me yet...

```
bambuko@LatitudeE641005543265:~$ lspci -knn | grep -iA3 'vga\|3d\|display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Latitude E6410 [1028:040a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

for reference:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr

and

https://youtu.be/MWNpSgX6Eg0

and

https://askubuntu.com/questions/73007/cant-set-a-higher-screen-resolution-in-a-external-display-in-a-dell-mini-10v-la

Comment: What is your laptop model?

Comment: And what is the model of the external display?

Comment: Cool! Does 2560x1440 become available for your Benq if you use extended mode while connecting it as secondary display? (you can use Win + P keycombo to cycle display modes once you plug the external display in)

Comment: Also another q: are you using VGA or DP cables? I do not see an HDMI port in the specs for your laptop.

Comment: Thank you for the images! That is definitely a DP cable. Nevertheless, we can try adding your native resolution to xrandr: Follow the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/73007/cant-set-a-higher-screen-resolution-in-a-external-display-in-a-dell-mini-10v-la and see if it works out for you. You will have to first run `xrandr --listactivemonitors` to see connected displays' IDs,

Comment: @Vlad you better paste this last comment as a reply (rather than comment)  :-) Looks promising - I will try it and report back. Thank you!!!

Comment: If that does not work, it would be worth exploring the option of additional drivers for your display cards, IF your laptop came with dual adapters: intel and nvidia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a solution!

I've spent all day trying various suggestions from interweb (all failing),

until I came upon this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599466/three-monitors-xrandr-configure-crtc-failed

I have experimented with various refresh rates instead of the typical 60Hz

50Hz still failed, 30Hz was outside the range (screen went black),

but with 40Hz it looks just perfect - here the view of 2560x1440 monitor with laptop screen below at 1280x800 working as one

[image]

This was achieved with following:

```
bambuko@LatitudeE641005543265:~$ cvt 2560 1440 40
# 2560x1440 39.96 Hz (CVT) hsync: 58.98 kHz; pclk: 201.00 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_40.00"  201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 1476 -hsync +vsync
```

Comment: Truly happy you made it work! Gonna clean up the other two answers detailing your journey and add them to the question as edits.

Comment: I wouldn't get there without your help - big thank you 