# Display fault 1440 x 900

Tags: display

I have a somewhat ancient HP monitor with a (16:10) 1440 x 900 resolution and a VGA cable (with an HDMI adapter) connected to an Intel NUC.

Elementary Horus recognises the monitor and its resolution but will not fill the screen when 16:10 is selected. Other resolutions will fill the screen. Though of course they do look a little funny and make navigating from difficult to entirely impractical.

Assuming that this isn't a hardware fault, is there anything that can be done to improve this prospect? Or will I have to summon up the courage to buy a new display?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Silly question, but do you have another HDMI adapter to try? The majority of resolution issues I’ve faced (primarily with projectors) are related to the adapter rather than the OS 

Comment: Give this a read https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/30118/how-can-i-determine-maximum-supported-display-resolution/30127#30127 and see if you can manage to play around with the refresh rates. The user there had to use xrandr to set a diff refresh rate for the external display to make the image fill the entire screen area. They were also dealing with some legacy devices, and using some display port/hdmi adapter I believe.

Comment: I'm afraid that I only have the one adapter. However, I can borrow a PC with a VGA port and try a more direct connection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the issue with refresh rates and legacy equipment. If I can find the time I'll definitely have a play with xrandr. Though I'll admit I was rather hoping for something a little more click and play.